# Regex for a string pattern split

Tags: java

Have a scenario to strip the below pattern strings -

```
abc|hjdj|kleygag|0|0|0|0|
ghys|jkugb|0|0|0
yuubf|kluygb|tyrffv|nutgv|0|0|0|0|0|
```

Looking for help to get a regex in java to separate these values excluding everything from the first occurence of pipe before 0, the output should look like-

```
abc|hjdj|kleygag
ghyd|jkugb
yuubf|kluygb|tyrffv|nutgv
```

Just need regex, which has been answered and been very helpful, would just be very helpful to know just the regex and not the complete code for the reverse pattern as requested in the followup question

Comment: Wow Nice Homework. Wait why tag [tag:python] and [tag:javascript]?

Comment: @Sushrta20 So you can get more downvotes for wrong tags? That is not very smart.

Comment: Edited the question, can this please taken off from hold? Or is there anything that needs to be changed with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is regex necessary for this?  `substring()` gets you want you want easily.

### Update

I saw a comment where you're also wanting a case where the data looks like, "0|0|0|0|abdc|ghyft|rtyu".  I've modified my answer to account for that case and a case where the data could be, "0|0|0|0|abdc|ghyft|rtyu|0|0|0|"

Either way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList(){
        {
            add("abc|hjdj|kleygag|0|0|0|0|");
            add("ghys|jkugb|0|0|0");
            add("yuubf|kluygb|tyrffv|nutgv|0|0|0|0|0|");
            add("0|0|0|0|abdc|ghyft|rtyu");
            add("0|0|0|0|abdc|ghyft|rtyu|0|0|0|0|0|");
        }
    };

    // Non Regex
    System.out.println("Non Regex");
    for (String string : strings) {
        int startIndex = -1;
        int endIndex = -1;
        // Find first non zero character
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            if ('a' <= string.charAt(i) && string.charAt(i) <= 'z') {
                startIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Find first pipe zero |0 after startIndex
        endIndex = string.indexOf("|0", startIndex);

        // Determine which substring() to use based on the endIndex results
        System.out.println(endIndex > -1 ? string.substring(startIndex, endIndex) : string.substring(startIndex));
    }
    System.out.println("");

    // Regex
    System.out.println("Regex");
    for (String string : strings) {
        System.out.println(string.replaceAll("\\|0|0\\||\\|$", ""));
    }
}
```

Results:

Non Regex

```
abc|hjdj|kleygag
ghys|jkugb
yuubf|kluygb|tyrffv|nutgv
abdc|ghyft|rtyu
abdc|ghyft|rtyu

Regex
abc|hjdj|kleygag
ghys|jkugb
yuubf|kluygb|tyrffv|nutgv
abdc|ghyft|rtyu
abdc|ghyft|rtyu
```

Comment: @Sushrta20 I saw your comment about where the "|0" appearing in different areas of the data.  I've updated my answer to account for the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\|0|0\||\|$
```

Java code:

```
String regex = "\\|0|0\\|\\|$";

System.out.println("abc|hjdj|kleygag|0|0|0|0|".replaceAll(regex, ""));
System.out.println("ghys|jkugb|0|0|0".replaceAll(regex, ""));
System.out.println("yuubf|kluygb|tyrffv|nutgv|0|0|0|0|0|".replaceAll(regex, ""));
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked but also need help with the values coming in as 0|0|0|0|abdc|ghyft|rtyu for a different field, need to strip off those 0 in the front and the output should be as abdc|ghyft|rtyu. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Sushrta20 I've updated the answer in case you need it

Comment: Thank you @shar1er80, also any suggestions on how to understand these regex notations always have hard time to figure out, I am novice to programming in Java.

Comment: Might be a final rule here if can please know regex help out- here is another set   |||||||||abdc|hjjs||ghdjj|hjdjd want to eliminate all pipes in the beginning only- tried this(\||\|$) but removes all pipes. Thanks

Comment: @Sushrta20 you can use this regex: `^\|*|\|0|0\||\|$`